# Convert .on() to .live() backward compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using hammer.js with a cms that only has 1.6 jquery.  So the function "on()' is not available instead I must use "live()",  There are two instances of it

1.

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(element[0], { drag_lock_to_axis: true });
hammertime.on("release dragleft dragright swipeleft swiperight", handleHammer);
```

2.

```
this.init = function() {
        setPaneDimensions();

        $(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function() {
            setPaneDimensions();
```

jQuery CANNOT be updated as the new document.ready does not work with the flow of the javascript, order of operations

Can anyone help me convert these two functions?  I am at a loss as to how?

Comment: 1.6 has access to .delegate, which uses a near identical syntax to .on (the event names and selector are swapped.).

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Replace .on with .delegate. Better solution is using jQuery.noConfilict

Comment: There's no "can not be updated", that's just laziness. Update jQuery and rewrite what you have to.

Comment: @adeneo in an ideal world, that would indeed be the case.

Comment: @KevinB - I realize it might not always be possible, but in this case it would probably be easier to update the CMS to work with a newer version of jQuery (and there is no new document.ready ?) instead of rewriting every plugin you'd like to use, as almost everything these days is jQuery 1.7+, at least!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i were confronted with this problem and the only option was to use 1.6, i would polyfill .on so that later when i was able to upgrade from 1.6 to 1.9+, it would seamlessly upgrade.

```
(function($){
    if (!$.fn.on) {
        $.fn.on = function(events,selector,data,handler){
            if (typeof selector !== "string") {
                return this.bind.apply(this,arguments);
            }
            return this.delegate(selector,events,data,handler)
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

(this is intended to be included as a standalone external script, after you include jquery)

http://jsfiddle.net/Nt8Q8/